# What happens when SEM is conducted with a rank-based DV?

Tags: nonparametric, structural-equation-modeling

Can SEM be conducted with a rank-based dependent variable? If so, which software package would be the way to go?

Obviously, you'll get LISREL output and such, but I'm concerned as to how the rank-based DV would affect parameter estimates and was wondering if something can be done to combat any bad things that come from ignoring the distributional assumption of the DV.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are methods for analyzing rank based endogenous variables in SEM. These are based on either polychoric correlations, or or ordinal/probit regression.

LISREL uses the polychoric correlation methods (I believe). Mplus and Lavaan use ordinal logistic/probit methods.

Because you're using an appropriate method, there are no bad things that happen.

Here's an example, comparing polr() in R with lavaan.

Set up the data:

```
library(lavaan)
set.seed(54321)
y <- sample(1:5, 1000, TRUE)
x <- runif(1000)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(y, x))
d$y <- ordered(d$y)
```

Run polr:

```
> fit1 <- polr(y ~ x, data=d)
> summary(fit1)

Re-fitting to get Hessian

Call:
polr(formula = y ~ x, data = d)

Coefficients:
Value Std. Error t value
x -0.1445     0.1914 -0.7553

Intercepts:
    Value    Std. Error t value 
1|2  -1.4638   0.1233   -11.8671
2|3  -0.4434   0.1142    -3.8835
3|4   0.3597   0.1139     3.1590
4|5   1.2790   0.1213    10.5468

Residual Deviance: 3216.968 
AIC: 3226.968
```

Run very simple model in Lavaan:

```
> fit2 <- sem(myModel, data=d, estimator="WLSMV")
> summary(fit2)

                   Estimate  Std.err  Z-value  P(>|z|)
Regressions:
  y ~
    x                -0.086    0.118   -0.732    0.464

Thresholds:
    y|t1             -0.887    0.072  -12.314    0.000
    y|t2             -0.275    0.069   -3.967    0.000
    y|t3              0.227    0.069    3.276    0.001
    y|t4              0.779    0.071   10.907    0.000
```

Notice that the z/t-values are almsot the same ( 0.732 for lavaan,  0.755 for polr). The coefficients are about 1.6 times higher in polr than in lavaan because polr uses a logistic link function by default, but lavaan uses probit. If you add method="probit" to the polr, the parameter estimates will be almost identical.

Comment: Thanks for this. I would upvote this, but I don't have enough reputation to. (I'm also a little starstruck, as "Discovering Statistics using R" is one of my favorite texts.

I look forward to being able to give back to the community more as I grow in my own knowledge!

Comment: Thanks for the nice comments. All the good bits were Andy or Zoe, not me :)

Comment: (+1) Surely you mean "endogenous" in the first paragraph instead of exogenous?